Get snapshot of keys in Caffeine
I have a simple registry implemented as Caffeine cache:
class LocalFactorsRegistry(
    duration: Duration,
) : FactorsRegistry {
    private val factors =
        Caffeine
            .newBuilder()
            .expireAfterWrite(duration)
            .build<String, Boolean>()

    override fun getUsedFactors(): Set<String> = factors.asMap().keys

    override fun markFactorAsUsed(factorId: String) {
        factors.put(factorId, true)
    }
}

I try to test if item is evicted:
    @Test
    fun `should mark factor as used and wait for expiration`() {
        val factory = LocalFactorsRegistry(Duration.ofMillis(100))

        factory.getUsedFactors() shouldBe emptySet()

        factory.markFactorAsUsed("factor2")

        Thread.sleep(100)

        factory.getUsedFactors() shouldBe emptySet()
    }

However tests fails on last assertion:
java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.BoundedLocalCache$EntryIterator.nextKey(BoundedLocalCache.java:3754)
    at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.BoundedLocalCache$KeyIterator.next(BoundedLocalCache.java:3350)
    at kotlin.collections.CollectionsKt___CollectionsKt.toList(_Collections.kt:1323)
    at io.kotest.assertions.print.IterablePrint.print(IterablePrint.kt:6)
    at io.kotest.assertions.print.IterablePrint.print(IterablePrint.kt:3)
    at io.kotest.assertions.print.PrintKt.print(Print.kt:48)
    at io.kotest.assertions.eq.IterableEq.generateError(IterableEq.kt:221)
    at io.kotest.assertions.eq.IterableEq.checkSetEquality(IterableEq.kt:77)
    at io.kotest.assertions.eq.IterableEq.equals(IterableEq.kt:65)
    at io.kotest.assertions.eq.EqKt.eq(Eq.kt:51)
    at io.kotest.assertions.eq.EqKt.eq(Eq.kt:66)
    at io.kotest.matchers.ShouldKt$equalityMatcher$1.test(should.kt:73)
    at io.kotest.matchers.ShouldKt.invokeMatcher(should.kt:38)
    at io.kotest.matchers.ShouldKt.should(should.kt:33)
    at io.kotest.matchers.ShouldKt.shouldBe(should.kt:17)
    at com.example.LocalFactorsRegistryTest.should mark factor as used and wait for expiration(AbstractFactorsRegistryTest.kt:35)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1596)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1596)

I wonder how I can get an immutable snapshot of keys in the caffeine cache to assert it properly.

Explained on the github issue. The user needs to trigger a cleanUp() and the rest are Kotlin's bugs.

@BenManes you can convert this comment into an answer so I could accept it

@BenManes as I wrote in GH comment - I was able to reproduce it in pure Java

As documented, the size is an estimate and cleanUp() may be called prior to perform any pending evictions. The iterator suppresses entries that are pending eviction when encountered as the cache should not return back stale content. This complies with the Collection Framework and Kotlin's unsafe behavior should be at least documented (ideally fixed since that is trivially easy to resolve).

As mentioned by @ben-manes cleanUp() needs to be called prior factors.asMap().keys
